# Warning when users access website page with self-signed certificates

Tags: security, ssl, web

I made a self-signed certificate for a specific page for my website.
It generates a "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" warning.

I'd like to ask if that is normal and is there any way to remove the warning?

Comment: Yep, it's quite normal. The browser knows it hasn't been signed by a "trusted" certificate authority so it throws that warning at the user to let them know while there's a certificate being used, the certificate itself is not trusted. Solutions (non-exhaustive): (1) purchase a certificate from a well-known certificate authority, or (2), trust the certificate/CA from your self-signed certificate on the machine you are trying to connect from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to ask if that is normal ...

Yes, its normal. Browsers carry around their own list of trust anchors, and your self signed certificate is not in the list by default. There's some hand waiving since [Chromium uses the trust store of the underlying OS](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy).

You can add a self signed certificate to the trusted list. See, for example, [Configuring a browser to work with self-signed certificates](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/clmhelp/v4r0m3/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.rational.rrdi.admin.doc/topics/t_browser_ss_cert.html).

> ... is there any way to remove the warning?

No, there's no way to remove the warning. If it was possible, then bad guys would be doing it to unsuspecting users.

You can avoid the warning in the first place by using a certificate that chains back to a trust anchor in the browsers. You might try [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) or [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/) for a certificate. They offer free Class 1 server certificates. The certificates are trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. Class 1's are domain validated via email and *don't* allow wildcards. If you need a wildcard, then you'll have to purchase a Class 2 or higher. Startcom and CAcert charge for revocation, if needed.